# excel loosing data/becoming corrupt using OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am trying to save some content in excel. After saving i am giving option of download.
My code is :

```
  private void OpenWorkSheet(string workbookName, FormCollection frm)
        {

            using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(workbookName,true))
            {
                var workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
                var workbook = workbookPart.Workbook;
                var sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().ToList();
                Worksheet worksheet1 = ((WorksheetPart)(workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet[0].Id))).Worksheet;

                if (sheet == null)
                    throw new Exception("No sheet found in the template file. Please add the sheet");

                //insertion in sheet1
                ExcelOxml.SetCellValue(document, worksheet1, 3, 6, Convert.ToString(frm["ACName"]), false);
                ExcelOxml.SetCellValue(document, worksheet1, 3, 8, Convert.ToString(frm["AcNum"]), false);


                bool setv = ExcelOxml.SetSpreadsheetCellValue(worksheet1, "F", 6, Convert.ToString(frm["name"]));
                setv = ExcelOxml.SetSpreadsheetCellValue(worksheet1, "F", 8, Convert.ToString(frm["newvexpansion"]));
                setv = ExcelOxml.SetSpreadsheetCellValue(worksheet1, "F", 10, Convert.ToString(frm["userdefinedsegment"]));

                worksheet1.Save();


                document.Close();

        // Download logic   
                string XlsPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/ExcelTemplate/GCG Pricing.xlsm");
                FileInfo fileDet = new System.IO.FileInfo(XlsPath);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
                Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(fileDet.Name));
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileDet.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                Response.WriteFile(fileDet.FullName);
                Response.End();

            }
        }
```

Once data is saved i get option of opening/Saving file once i save it in local machine. And open it it gives error as :

Excel found unreadable content in 'GCG+Pricing.xlsm'.Do you want to trecove the contents of this workbook ? If you trust the source of this workbook.click Yes.

My file name is GCG Pricing.xlsm however after downloading it becomes GCG+Pricing.xlsm.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you open it prior to downloading? The download part seems kind of irrelevant to the question unless that's the bit that's corrupting it. More likely is you're saving a corrupt document

Comment: Try installing the Visual Basic component in Office 2010

Comment: What is `ExcelOxml` I can't find a reference to it online, so I'd say whatever is writing your Open XML is writing something incorrectly.